# least square means for GLMM ANOVA

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lsmeans

I'm using `glm` with `family=Gamma(link=identity)` for gamma distributed data, where I am comparing variance across groups and their interaction (data are balanced as it's a repeated design). I'm then doing a posthoc test as follows:

`lsmeans(model,pairwise ~ group1*group2,adjust="tukey")`

My question is: does such a model correct for non-normality when generating ls means? I want to be able to report some descriptive stats from this model and I'm wondering if the ls means and CI or SE are ok to report?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no. Least-squares means summarize a model, not a data set. If the model is inappropriate, then so are the LS means. Fit a model that is suitable for the data; then the LS means for that model will also be suitable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm just a bit confused by you first saying no, then yes if the model is fit for the data. For example, `glm` with `family=Gamma(link=identity)` is considered suitable for reaction time data. Would the suitability of this model to the data also make the LS means suitable?